# Swing alphanumeric keypad

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing a keypad, that should work like a mobile phone keypad, and wondering how to manage the choice we have in a single key.  For exemple the key with number 1 has also letters ABC, and continuously clicking the key within less than x seconds permits to change from 1 to A to B to C to 1 again and if we are over x seconds we are back to initial state with the number 1.  I guess there is a use of timer but I don't really see how to make use of it.  Thanks for advice and guidelines.

Comment: *"I'm doing a mobile phone keypad"*  What mobile phone supports Swing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need a timer.

In the action listener for the key, the first thing you do is get the current time.

You compare the current time with the time that the key was last pressed (previous time).

if the time difference is less than x seconds, shift the value of the key from 1 to A, A to B, B to C, or C to 1.

If the time difference is more than x seconds, set the value of the key to 1.

Somehow, you have to determine what type of key press actually sends the character to the display.

After processing, save the current time as the previous time.

Comment: Allright, I haven't tried that yet but it seems good to me :).  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Each time your action listener detects a click, get current time and compare with previous current time (which you had stored the previous time the action listener detected a click).

Answer (score 1):

In the listener of your buttons, save the last time the interrupt ocurred with `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

If the difference between the current time and the last time is lower than the timeout, return the next character, else return the first.