# Java Swing Alphanumeric Keypad

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to build a 'dumb' phone and hence i need to build an alphanumerical keypad. So the deal is for each button, if they're pressed repeatedly within a certain time limit (2 seconds) the characters they input change. For instance, pressing 1 inputs A, but if it's pressed again in 2 seconds, the input is changed to B, then if it is pressed in 2 seconds again, the input is C and so on.

There's already a question relating exactly to this ( [Swing alphanumeric keypad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088870/swing-alphanumeric-keypad?answertab=active#tab-top)). I've been reading it all day and trying to make sense, but i can't..

I've come up with something like this (i'm aware it's probably really silly but my brain is really failing me to make it less silly), the following code is inside the action listener of the 1 button;

```
    long buttn_last_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    line.setText("A");
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - buttn_last_pressed) <= 2000) {
       line1.setText("B"); }
```

The problem with this is that the input always comes up as B. I'm really stuck and i can't get my head around this as you can see from the silly code i've come up with.. Any help will be appreciated very much,
Thank you very much in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

So, if we have a look at this snippet...

```
long buttn_last_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
line.setText("A");
if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - buttn_last_pressed) <= 2000) {
```

Unless `line.setText("A");` is really, really slow, it's unlikely to take 2 seconds to reach the `if` statement...

Do you mean something more like...

[image: Button]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class JavaApplication787 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JavaApplication787();
    }

    public JavaApplication787() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField field;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btn = new JButton("1 ABC");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                private long lastClick = -1;
                private int count;
                private String[] value = {"1", "A", "B", "C"};
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (now - lastClick < 2000) {
                        count++;
                        if (count >= value.length) {
                            count = 0;
                        }
                    } else {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    field.setText(value[count]);
                    lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            });
            field = new JTextField(4);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(btn, gbc);
            add(field, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Okay, so all this does is checks the difference between the time of the last click, if it's less than 2 seconds, it updates a `count`, indicating the current value to be used, otherwise, it resets the `count` to `0`, defaulting back to the normal key...

```
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    private long lastClick = -1;
    private int count;
    private String[] value = {"1", "A", "B", "C"};
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now - lastClick < 2000) {
            count++;
            if (count >= value.length) {
                count = 0;
            }
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
        field.setText(value[count]);
        lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
});
```

Comment: ah right ok i totally get it now - such a silly mistake i did!.. And yes, this is exactly what i wanted to do, you're a star, thank you veery much!! :)

Comment: But i don't gey why lastClick is initiated to -1, it would work the same if it wasn't, right?

Comment: It's a personal thing, I tend to set it to -1 one so I can check to see if it's set, in this it isn't required